# I need a scrollbar for a rectangle box with in the page of a pdf using apache pdfbox library?Is it possible , can anyone provide the proper info

Tags: java, pdfbox

Want to  get the scrollbar for a box
I am using Apache pdf box library, I am able to get the rectangle box in a page but I need to get a scroll bar for that box such that when I try to fill that box if content is extra it should get the scroll option .
By scrolling we should be able to see the data in the rectangle box

I got a rectangle box but I want scrollbar for the box

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've never seen this. If it exists, then it's JavaScript in a PDF. Which some people have disabled for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bars do not apply to pdf writers such as PDFBox.

They are a feature of  the rendering when manually editing fields. So here same form in 3 different viewers, both in render and edit modes. The scrollbars are needed for data input and not for display hence fields should be high enough to allow for printout as that's what a PDF was originally designed to do best.

A related problem is that all readers may draw text boxes in totally  different ways so fields are best avoided for multiline entries. Here there is no guarantee 3 entries will be visible. Only 2 lines will on average be printout/visible. Thus 3 single line entries should have been placed for the 3 entries requirement.

[image]